# Failed tests at official spring tutorial

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am trying to do the tutorial "Data Access with Spring" which is at this link http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/  at the official site of spring.
I have downloaded the code as it is but when I try to run the command ./gradlew test, the tests 
fail and I get this result:

```
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
[sts] Starting Gradle build for the following tasks: 
[sts]      test
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test

com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.integration.MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests > thatItemIsInsertedIntoCollectionHasCorrectIndexes FAILED
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33

com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.integration.MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests > thatItemCustomMappingWorks FAILED
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:28
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemMappingIntegrationTests.java:33

com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.integration.MenuItemRepositoryAnalyseIngredientsIntegrationTests > thatIngredientsAnalysisWorks FAILED
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network
                    Caused by: java.io.IOException

com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.integration.MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests > thatItemIsInsertedIntoRepoWorks FAILED
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:34
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:34
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:34
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:39
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:39
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemRepositoryFindByIngredientsIntegrationTests.java:39

com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.integration.MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests > thatItemIsInsertedIntoRepoWorks FAILED
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:30
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:30
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:30
    org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:35
        Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoException$Network at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:35
            Caused by: java.io.IOException at MenuItemRepositoryIntegrationTests.java:35

8 tests completed, 5 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/teopa_000/workspace/tut-data-3-complete/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 48.782 secs
[sts] Build failed
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:77)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.TaskUtil.execute(TaskUtil.java:95)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.launch.GradleProcess$1.doit(GradleProcess.java:97)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.util.GradleRunnable$1.run(GradleRunnable.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:85)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:108)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:68)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':test'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users/teopa_000/workspace/tut-data-3-complete/build/reports/tests/index.html
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.handleTestFailures(Test.java:1022)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.executeTests(Test.java:466)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 92 more
[sts] Time taken: 0 min, 49 sec
[sts] -----------------------------------------------------
```

If run the project through command line or through eclipse I get the same result.
Any idea why is this happening?
I don t change nothing from the code of the spring site and I don t understand why I get this result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the tests fail with the following exception:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network
```

So it's quite clear: the test can't reach your mongodb database. Make sure to follow the instructions at http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/2/ to install and start MongoDB.